Как сделать или есть готовый бот для распознавания слов на сервере Дискорд?
Идея в том что бы бот запоминал все сообщения и по ключевым словам которые можно было бы менять пересылал эти сообщения в текстовый канал на сервере или сразу в личку это не особо важно, прошу изъяснятся максимально простым языком так как я мало что в этом понимаю или просто кидайте ссылку на статью и я попробую разобраться
